# Converting a normal java program to map reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to write a Java wrapper which will convert 'compatible programs' into map reduce form to be executed by the Hadoop framework.
I am aware that my question is quite ambiguous.But this is what I intent to do.

- Take an input java program. user will specify which part of the
  program is to be executed by map reduce.
- This java program will be
  inputed by my program and it will feed the equivalent map reduce
  program to hadoop.

I am stuck on few points.

- Map reduce programs for each class will be different. How am I going
  to generalize it?
- From where I should start.
- What should be my approach for this problem?

Any suggestions are welcome. It will help me to decide further direction.

Answer (score 2):

It is impposible in general, not all program support MapReduce paradigm. MapReduce is a framework some task can be accomplished with it some are not. Best question you can ask youself to determine is alogrithm can benefit of map reduce usage.

1. Is there are parts which can be evaluated in parallel.
2. Do they have to be aggregated by some key
3. How much data need to be shared between each splits.
4. Can problem be solved with sequence/loop of step 1 to 3.

Comment: I agree with you yura. it seems impossible for now to convert any program to equivalent map reduce form. So I feel I should take some specific class of problems. What Im planning now is to compare many map reduce programs and their normal Java programs to see if I get any hint.

Comment: @user981630 Yes, read book about algorithms in mpa reduce and you will understand how its works. http://www.amazon.com/Data-Intensive-Processing-MapReduce-Synthesis-Technologies/dp/1608453421%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIIBINOD46VC3JCLQ%26tag%3Dws%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D1608453421

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/streaming.html). You would be able to write map/reduce functions in any language which can read/write to the STDOUT/STDIN and then hook them to Apache Hadoop. [Here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) is a nice tutorial on how to create MapReduce jobs using compatible Python map/reduce functions.

Comment: Thnx praveen,but here one will have to write map and reduce functions which I want to avoid. I want to take normal Java program(I have fixed my language to java for now), and try to run it in parallel using map reduce. I will also have to identify regions - If any- which can be parallelised.

Comment: Hadoop f/w expects your program to work with key/value pairs. I don't think you can just arbitrarily some take some java or any language code and fit it in Hadoop.